# Want to assign char value using if condition - C language

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am practicing to make a marks sheet where I want to assign subjects grade in a variable using an `if` condition.

Here `eper` is subject percentage that I want to check and store it accordingly in a variable.

```
if(eper >=80){  
    geng = "A";
}
```

Please do not confuse me with arrays and loops as I am in a learning phase and I am still at beginners level and have not studied loops and arrays yet.

Comment: `"A"` is a string (a character pointer); `'A'` is a single character.  What is the type of `geng`?  If you have `const char *geng;` then what you wrote is fine.  If you have `char geng;`, then you need the single character form.  If you have something else, you need to show what you've got — it is likely to be unorthodox, but may 'work OK' if you use `'A'`.

Comment: In other words change `geng = "A";` to `geng = 'A';` (presuming you have declared `char geng;` earlier (preferably initialized as `char geng = 0;`))

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and learn [ask].

Comment: @Olaf That page ought to mention that questions end with a question mark ... something completely missing here.

Comment: @JimBalter: One should have learned that at school. (Well ....)

Answer (score 3):

As you have seen through the comments, an assignment with double-quotes (`""`) assigns a *string value* to the variable on the left. To assign a single character to the variable on the left, you need to use *single quotes* to demonstrate it is a *character* and not a *string* assignment.

The following without loops, etc. demonstrates an approach your can use for *letter-grade* assignment based on a numeric value. The code below expects the student name to be given followed by a numeric grade (between `0-100`) that will be used to determine the letter-grade for the student:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 3) { /* validate sufficient number of arguments */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input. usage: %s name grade\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *student = argv[1];        /* declare/initialize variables */
    int  grade = atoi (argv[2]);
    char ltrgrade = 0;

    if (grade < 0 || 100 < grade) { /* validate grade in range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid grade input '%d'.\n", grade);
        return 1;
    }

    /* classify the grade with a letter grade */
    if (grade >= 90) 
        ltrgrade = 'A';
    else if (grade >= 80)
        ltrgrade = 'B';
    else if (grade >= 70)
        ltrgrade = 'C';
    else if (grade >= 60)
        ltrgrade = 'D';
    else
        ltrgrade = 'F';

    /* print the results */
    printf ("\n %-12s  %3d  (%c)\n\n", student, grade, ltrgrade);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stdgrade sally 82

 sally          82  (B)

$ ./bin/stdgrade Jonathan 90

 Jonathan       90  (A)
```

(see: Jonathan gets the gold star again `:)`

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I fear that some of the machinery you show may be more complicated than the OP is ready for, and you don't do anything about `stdgrade David 123456` (which only gets an A grade like Jonathan did, despite scoring so much more than Jonathan did).  I wonder what should happen with `stdgrade Aristotle 100 Einstein 100 Newton 99`?

Comment: C does not have strings, thus no "string value". The right side of the assignment decays to a _pointer_ to the first element of a _string literal_ (i.e. `const char []`). Beginner or not, we should use the correct terms. That way he should be able to further research on his own.

Comment: "C does not have strings" -- This is false. It doesn't have a string `type`, but it does have a conventional storage format for strings, and string constants and string functions that follow that format. But it certainly doesn't have "string assignment", so you're right ... that part is definitely wrong. "we should use the correct terms" -- yeah, of only. "const char []" -- nope; they aren't `const` in C, only C++.

Comment: @Olaf, Jim, perhaps I'm just getting too old and senile. When I say string, I mean type `char *` or type `char[]` with a `'\0'` at the end. Sorry for any confusion in my lack of clarity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - what are your saying? `./bin/stdgrade david 123456` gets `error: invalid grade input '123456'.` and `./bin/stdgrade Aristotle 100 Einstein 100 Newton 99` results in `Aristotle     100  (A)`, with neither `Einstein 100` or `Newton 99` processed because they were never intended to be processed in a single input example. Am I missing the intent of your comment?

Comment: I missed a paragraph so the out of range numbers are detected — my bad.  I would simply replace the `if (argc < 3)` condition with `if (argc != 3)` so that if there's an attempt to abuse the program by passing too many arguments, that's reported.  It is pretty minor stuff (especially since I missed the range check).

Comment: Agreed, fixed -- you still get an `'A'`...

Comment: @JimBalter: Greed, I meant "string type". Basically, it is just convention when a `char []` is treated as a character sequence or not. For _string literals_ being `const`: If you use them as an object themselves, they [technically are](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7), although the standard does not explicitly state this in p6. They are not if you use them to initialise a `char []`, because the literal itself is just copied to the array. The problem is if you assign them to `char *` in C. Here the `const` qualifier is silently ignored. ...

Comment: @JimBalter: ... Not clearly stating they are `const` might be for legacy reasons. IIRC, old K&R C (not sure about C90, though) _string_ literals were read/write.

Comment: "they technically are" -- Nonsense ... they are *technically* type `char[]` and *not* type `const char[]`, and thus can legally be assigned to `char*` variables or parameters. It's amusing that you impose your error on the standard by so radically misusing the word "technically", but I've seen this sort of thing from you before. That's my last comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the concept of *types*.

The meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function is determined by the type of the expression used to access it. For the statement,

```
geng = "A";
```

there are two types which are relevant. The type of the expression `geng`, and the type of the expression `"A"`. The types of the two expressions must be compatible in the ways the standard specifies, but in this case it's sufficient to say they must be of the same type. To see all the rules, find §6.5.16.1 of the C11 standard - fair warning, it's hard to read.

Now, let's figure out the type of `"A"`. `"A"` is a *string literal*, and their type is *array of `char`*. It's handy to note here that `'A'` (in single quotes) specifies a single *character constant*, has type `int`, and might be what you wanted instead.

So we have a few cases at hand:

- if you meant for `geng` to be a single character, the appropriate type is either `int`, or `char`. If its possible values arise only from character constants, it's safe to choose: `char geng = 'A';`
- if `geng` is supposed to represent character constants but its values are the result of function calls to e.g. `fgetc`, `int` is the appropriate type
- if you meant for `geng` to hold strings, such as `"A"`, for convenience further in the code (like concatenating with other strings, or somesuch), you should specify: `const char geng[] = "A";` **or** `const char *geng = "A";`, depending on how you will use it, whether you will modify it or not, etc.

Comment: "their type is array of const char" -- no, not const in C (only in C++). Of course, writing to them is undefined behavior. This wacky design is a historical remnant. `const char geng[] = "A"; or const char *geng = "A";` -- these are initializations, not assignments, so I don't see how they are helpful here. TMI won't serve the OP well.